# Does sexually stimulating yourself break your fast?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, masturbation

I unfortunately have a huge addiction called masturbation. I've been trying to stop, and this ramadan, during fasting hours, I couldn't help myself and I masturbated to the point where I was about to ejaculate. It was so close, analogy being, like going to the store, and opening the door and just about to take the step in
 although I didn't ejaculate.

Does this break my fast or not, and if it did, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you didn't ejaculate, your fasting is correct, but you have committed sin. However, if you did ejaculate while fasting, your fasting will be spoilt, then you have to make kadaa' and fast the same number of days you spoilt by ejaculation or masturbation.

Comment: What does ejaculation have anything to do with breaking fast?  If one has sex with wife, even if he/she doesn't ejaculate, the kafara is the same.

Comment: That's the point, kafara is required only for inserting the male's orfan into the female's organ, whether he ejaculated or not, a kafara is required. But if ejaculation occured without intercourse, it spoils fasting and kadaa' is required after ramadan. And the reason for why ejaculation spoils fast is that one of the reasons that Allah ordered us to fast for is to leave our temptations and desires for his sake. And look here http://islamqa.info/en/2571